# Gradle keeps moving project outside of parent

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradlew

I am seeing some odd behavior with Gradle. Everytime I sync Gradle with Intellij it shows a 'mirrored' copy of the project outside of the parent project with certain dependency cache hashes.

[image]

Apologies for the redaction, but as you can see, the subproject "service" gets moved outside of the parent project when intellij syncs (service_main).

I have tried removing the .idea directory and re-importing as well as the .gradle directory but it keeps moving. Also, when i make a change to a file it reflects in the outside project as well.

I am using Gradle 4.5 with Intellij Ultimate 2018.1.

What is going on here?

Comment: Please add the code of your Gradle files (`build.gradle`, possible `settings.gradle`).

Comment: Avoid symlinks: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135921

Comment: Update: I checked for symlinks, there are none. So i removed my entire project and recloned. When i cloned my develop branch everything worked as normal. When i reapplied my changes (upgrade to springboot 2.0) the issue appeared again. The hashed files at the top are all tomcat dependencies as well.

Comment: @hitch.united I'm facing the same issue with IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3, Gradle and Spring Boot 2.x. Have you ever found a solution for that?

Comment: @CrazyCoder The exact same issue is happening to me as well and doesn't seem to have any symlinks in the project.

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin Still no solution to this.